# How to Convert String with printing control character to formatted String?

Tags: java, printing

The problem is the source contains control character. Those control characters is invisible in Notepad. Text file viewer such as notepad does not display text in proper format.

For example(\r\n are control characters which are invisible in notepad):

Originial

```
AAAAAA                           123.00\r
           BBBBBBB\r\n
```

Final Result

```
AAAAAA     BBBBBBB               123.00\r\n
```

The term seems to be "overprinting".
Is there any way to convert such a String?
Or is there any way to simulate a printer that print such text?

Sample Code

```
String text = getUnformatedText();
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("text.txt")));
bw.write(text);
bw.flush();
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding the question. You could run a `replaceAll("\\r","\r")` and `replaceAll("\\r\\n","\r\n")` over the string containig yor characters. It is not clear if this is your oroblem.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here...

Comment: show a line of code where you get your source and the line of code you use to print it out and maybe someone else will have a clue what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to simulate the overprinting you have to write some code.  Shouldn't be that hard -- just break lines at `\r` and `\n` and expand `\t` appropriately, then map into a character buffer.

Comment: so what I need to do is merge lines if there is a `\r`? if t[i] is `\r`, then move cursor back to the last `\r\n`. If t[i] is `\n`, just replace it as `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a project at Google Project Hosting. The code works with my situation.
http://code.google.com/p/printing-control-text-to-notepad-ready/